# Why can I create Comparable objects with operator "new"?

Tags: java, generics

Why is

```
new Comparable[]
```

correct code in Java? I have seen code like this

```
public class ArrayHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Heap<T> {

    ...

public ArrayHeap(int capacity) {
    heap = (T[]) new Comparable[capacity];
}
```

I confused over the code

`heap = (T[]) new Comparable[capacity];`

because Comparable is interface and you can't create interface objects with operator "new". Could you, please, explain me, why I am wrong?

I don't even how to explain this phenomena!

Comment: You are **not** creating a `Comparable`, you are creating an **array** of comparables.

Comment: Well, then I can write it with any interface?

Comment: Since you can do it with `Comparable`, there is no reason that it won't work with another interface.

Comment: Well, now I understand what array `Comparable<String>[] comaparblesArray = new Comparable[10];` stores. Pointer `comparable` has interface type `Comparable`, but array objects has type `String` or any subclass of `String`.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов minor nitpick: `String` is `final`, it can't have subclasses.

Comment: Meanwhile, I can't write `Comparable<String> comparable = new Comparable<String>("some text");` where I really try to create interface object explicitly.

Comment: You **can't** instantiate interface directly. You can however instantiate `String` because it is a class. You can do `yourComparableArray[0] = "some string"`, because a `String` **is** `Comparable` - `String` *implements* `Comparable`. You are instantiating concrete classes, which can be represented as some interface, because they implement it.

Answer (score 3):

`new Comparable[]` doesn't create a `Comparable` object, it creates an array object of `Comparables`s.

Also, it's not correct Java code, because you need to give the array's size like in your second piece of code, ie `new Comparable[size]`.

Comment: Well, may I create arrays of fixed size of any Interface?

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов yes. Caveat though, since `Comparable` is a generic type (`Comparable<T>`), the created array will be of type `Comparable<Object>`. You should also get a compiler warning because of that.

Comment: Well, then all pointers inside Comparable array must be 'null'.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов well yes, until you put something into it they are.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов no, it will be all `null`s after creation (as Federico says), but you can fill it: `var comps = new Comparable[3]; comps[0] = "";` is perfectly fine (because "" is a `String` and `String` is `Comparable`).

Comment: But that means I created interface object. It shouldn't be legal, to my mind.

Comment: No, you created objects implementing that interface and stored them in an array for that interface. What makes you think it should be illegal?

Comment: Because I read in Key Horstmann that you can't create interface object. But even in Eclispe I wrote "comparable[1] = new String("popa");" and it compiled without errors.

Comment: Probably, for example, I should intepret code `Comparable<String>[] comparable = new Comparable[10];` like ten objects of class String that implements interface Comparable or its subclass that impelements this interface too.

Comment: You could just interpret it as an empty box that fits ten `Comparable` objects.

Comment: @АлександрСкворцов Think of an interface as a contract. By implementing an interface, a class promises to abide by that contract, that is, promises to implement the methods listed in the interface. An array (or a `Collection`) of that interface type is a container to hold objects of any class implementing that interface, meeting the terms of that contract. If `Dog`, `Cat`, & `Bird` all implement the interface `Animal`, then you can put objects of any or all of those classes into an array defined as holding `Animal`: `Animal[] animals = new Animal[ 15 ] ;` … `animals[0] = new Cat( "Fluffy" ) ;`